# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder compression

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

How do you enable compression (e.g. GZIP) for producers using the Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires a correction in the documentation.

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.producer.compressionType=gzip`

Comment: Hrm... this doesn't seem to work for me. Does something need to be enabled on Kafka's side to get this to work?

Comment: Can you share what you are doing? I have `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.compressionType=gzip` and I can see the property propagated the `KafkaProducer`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't put the code up on the internet. We were watching the Kafka topics directly (by tailing their log files) and the contents weren't compressed. If it's working for you, then it's probably a config issue on our side. I'll see if I can look into it further. Thanks for your help!